# Переместить конкретное слово в тексте на первое место

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Подскажите, пжл, знатоки!

Как должна выглядеть формула, чтобы конкретное слово в ячейке можно было поставить с конца или середины на первое место.
Например много данных со словом "**купить**"

- навигатор гармин купить,
- Навигатор купить Гармин,
- Навигатор 444 гпс гармин купить и т.д.

Надо чтобы слово "**купить**" автоматом ставилось в начало фразы в ячейке
то есть: "купить навигатор гармин"

Comment: Это должна быть не формула, а vba скрипт или макрос. Логика: после ввода происходит проверка ячейки, и при наличии нужного слова - перемещение его в начало текста. Код, к сожалению, сразу так подсказать не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логика формулы: если слово в тексте есть, сцепляем это слово с текстом, из которого оно удалено, чистим полученную фразу от лишних пробелов; если слова нет, текст остается без изменений.

Проверяем наличие слова в тексте:

```
ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК("купить";A1))
```

Удаляем слово из текста

```
ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"купить";)
```

*СЖПРОБЕЛЫ* удалят лишние пробелы:

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ЕСЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК("купить";A1));"Купить "&ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"купить";);"Купить";);A1))
```

Если нужно при перестановке слова первую букву исходного текста сделать строчной:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК("купить";A1));"Купить "&СТРОЧН(ЛЕВБ(СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"купить";);"Купить";))))&ПСТР(СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"купить";);"Купить";));2;99);A1)
```

Нужно помнить, что при этом с маленькой буквы напишется и имя собственное, если оно было записано первым словом или если вторым после слова "купить".

Comment: Спасибо огромное человеческое! Как облегчился мой труд)

Comment: А можно эту формулу еще как -то поправить, потому что когда протягиваю ее на весь столбец, то на таких фразах где слово "купить" вначале на первом месте,  получается двойное  "Купить купить навигатор Гармин 64" (то есть слово купить дважды ставится)

Comment: Заменил формулу